# key constraint fails - what does it mean?

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error, when saving data to my db:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`samplelist_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SAMPLELIST_ITEM_SAMPLELIST` 
>   FOREIGN KEY (`samplelist_id`) REFERENCES `samplelist` (`samplelist_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: may i know your mysql engine? is that innoDB or MyISAM

Comment: Not sure, I set the tables samplelist and samplelist_item to innodb. Some of the tables in my db are myisam, im sure of that.

Comment: have you checked whether innoDb supports foreignkey

Comment: @SamArulRaj: MyISAM will never complain about foreign keys because it does not support them. InnoDB is the only (AFAIK) engine that supports FK constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes ,you are correct http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html,,,the problem may be because of this....i suspect

Comment: check my answer it clearly tells from the Mysql manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to add a row to a table with a foreign key, but the value you're specifying for the foreign key column does not have a match in the foreign table.

Comment: So what is missing in which table iyo?

Comment: It looks like the value that you are trying to set for `samplelist_id` in `samplelist_item` doesn't have a matching row in `samplelist`.

Comment: Yes, a row in `samplelist` with the same value for `samplelist_id` as you are trying to set in the new (or updated) row in `samplelist_item`.

Comment: I checked my DB and only samlpelist has one row, but not samplelist_item. There must be an tiem for every row and thats not true and thats the problem you say?

Comment: @EOB yes each samplelist_id you are adding in samplelist_item table must already exist in the samplelist_id column of the samplelist table.

Answer (score 1):

[Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**This would be the problem from Manual**

InnoDB rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table. When an UPDATE or DELETE operation affects a key value in the parent table that has matching rows in the child table, the result depends on the referential action specified using ON UPDATE and ON DELETE subclauses of the FOREIGN KEY clause. InnoDB supports five options regarding the action to be taken. If ON DELETE or ON UPDATE are not specified, the default action is RESTRICT.

Comment: yes it would because ,,may be your child table has the reference to your parent,, so it will so an error as you get for this situation.